# What is the correct way to add new element to @AppStorage stored Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, appstorage

The Number struct shows below:

```swift
struct Number: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var number: Int
    var flag = false
    // var description: String = "abc"
}
```

The default array shows below:

```swift
@AppStorage("numbers") var numbers: [Number] = [
    Number(id: 0, number: 1),
    Number(id: 1, number: 1),
    Number(id: 2, number: 1),
    Number(id: 3, number: 1),
    // Number(id: 4, number: 1),
]
```

User will change the number or flag when using this app and numbers can be stored successfully and the changes can also stored.

However, sometimes in the next app version, I will add a new element to the numbers such as `Number(id: 4, number: 1)`. And when I run the app again, the id 4 number not appeared in the list unless nothing changed to the numbers. What's more, when I add a new property to the struct such as `var description: String = "abc"`, when I run the app, the former changes will disappear. How can I deal with these problems?

The extension of Array shows in the following:

```swift
extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
        else { return nil }
        self = result
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

How can I deal with these problems?

Comment: `AppStorage` is only meant for small things like settings and such. This type of data should not be stored in it. Use some other form storage such as a file, CoreData, Firebase, AWS, etc.

Answer (score -1):

There are two different problems with two different approaches.

**1. add new array member**
In principle it's no problem to let the `AppStorage`array grow. But the app will at start try to read it's old saved values, and only use the default values if it can't read saved values. So adding `Number(id: 4, number: 1)` to the default values won't do anything, because the app can and will still read the old saved values (with only elements 0-3 in it).
You would have to add the 5th element programmatically to the `AppStorage` array at first start of the new app version.

**2. change array type by adding new properties**
If you add your new String property to `Number` in the next App version, the already saved AppStorage can't be decoded anymore based on the changed `Number` type, so it will fall back to default values.
You either have to adapt the decoding routine in the Array extension to cater for that on first App run, or introduce a new, second `AppStorage` type and transfer data from old type to new type on first run.

Here is a simple dummy:

```
struct Number: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var number: Int
    var flag = false
//     var description: String = "abc"
}

struct NewNumber: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var number: Int
    var flag = false
    var description: String = "abc" // new property
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("numbers") var numbers: [Number] = [
        Number(id: 0, number: 1),
        Number(id: 1, number: 0),
        Number(id: 2, number: 1),
        Number(id: 3, number: 0),
//        Number(id: 4, number: 0),
    ]
    
    @AppStorage("newNumbers") var newNumbers: [NewNumber] = [] // new AppStorage with new property

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            
            List($numbers) { $nr in
                HStack {
                    Text("Item \(nr.id): \(nr.number)")
                    Stepper("", value: $nr.number)
                }
            }
            
            Button("Add id: 4") { numbers.append(Number(id: 4, number: 1))} // adding id 4 here

            List($newNumbers) { $nr in
                HStack {
                    Text("Item \(nr.id): \(nr.number), \(nr.description)")
                    Stepper("", value: $nr.number)
                }
            }

            Button("Change to new struct") {
                newNumbers = []
                for nr in numbers {
                    newNumbers.append(NewNumber(id: nr.id, number: nr.number, flag: nr.flag))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```